# How to start a Qt frontend of a SystemC simulation

Tags: qt5, systemc

I am writing a GUI in Qt, where I have:

```
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
```

which is invoked by:

```
 app.exec();
```

Which returns only when the application terminates.

For executing SystemC simulation inside the application, I need to invoke:

```
sc_start(...);
```

Which also returns only when the simulation terminates.

Shall I hack Qt or SystemC to circumvent the problem, or is there some trick I can use? How can I avoid the deadlock of the two blocking calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run them inside two different threads or processes. And design a communication mechanism to exchange data between simulation and GUI.

Another common idea utilized by SystemC debuggers and interactive waveform viewers is to run SystemC under GDB and use GDB-MI protocol to control simulation from GUI.

Comment: Thanks. The first idea seems to better fro a release version. The second idea is more attractive, because myself is also planning interactive operation. Can you give hint to some source?

Comment: You can start with QtCreator source code, it already has GDB-MI implementation. I'm not aware of any systemc-specific open source GUI tools.